# webpack 2 + extract-text-webpack-plugin: parsing errors

Tags: sass, webpack-2, extract-text-plugin

I'm trying to make a webpack config for my project with some scss. Some of it comes from the root project and some scss I want to load from dependencies e.g. from `node_modules`. I'm running into a strange error where if I don't include the `node_modules` in the module, it get's built including some scss that I have in the root project. But if I add `include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')` or any other folder (eve one that doesn't exist) it fails but on file that is in root project and not in `node_modules`, the same files that it was extracting before with no errors.

Here is the webpack config:

```
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'style.css', disable: false, allChunks: true });

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        use:extractCSS.extract({
            fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
            loader: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
          })
      },
    ]
  }
```

So if I comment out the line with `include` it works but doesn't include `node_modules` and if I leave the line uncommented I get the error:

`Unexpected character '@' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.` in all of the scss files that are in the root project.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like you are missing a loader. Did you also install node-sass?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is not the absence of loader because if I don't include `node_modules` in to the module it works fine.